# How to resize and drag and move boxes between columns on a table using HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I found some questions on stackoverflow about resizing div elements already, but none of them get at quite what I'm looking for.  What I'm curious about it demonstrated perfectly [here](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/dhtmlgoodies-week-planner/dhtmlgoodies-week-planner.html)

If you hold down the mouse, you can create a new event.  You can drag the boxes from the top or bottom to lengthen the event, and you can move the boxes between columns (and it will always occupy the full width of that column when moved into it. I want to know how something like this is accomplished in HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: With jQueryUI you can do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/G5t6t/1/).

Comment: This may be something you are interested in as well https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets